# Debugging of 128 point FFT

Tags: vhdl

I'm implementing **128 point fft** using **IP CORE**. In **datasheeet of FFT IP** core  v-7 DS260 it is mentioned that input must be given in 2's complement form and in fixedpoint representation.
Can anyone tell me that how should i give input ( i.e,2's complement + fixed point or only 2's comp or only fixed point    )??
early reply will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the datasheet tells to use fixed point 2s complement, then use that?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std;
```

...and:

```
signal myData : signed(31 downto 0);
```

VHDL does not understand fixed points (excluding the ieee_proposed fixed point package?) so you just mentally keep track of where the decimal/binary point is.

If the format is 1.15.16 (32bit) then you know that first bit is the sign, 15 next bits are integer and rest of the 16bit are fractions.